# Called object type 'auto' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, template-meta-programming

I'm seeing a strange error from Clang (3.4 and 3.5) when I try to compile this C++14 code that uses a variable template of lambda type.

[Here's the C++14 code as I'd like to write it.](http://goo.gl/ESb0Mn)

[Here's a second version](http://goo.gl/qgFajl), with some of the library `_t` and `_v` stuff removed to make the compiler happy:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
class forward_if_wrapper {

    template <class U, class Enable = typename std::enable_if<std::is_lvalue_reference<U>::value>::type>
    static U forward(U&& u) {
        return u;
    }

    template <class U, class Enable = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_lvalue_reference<U>::value>::type>
    static U&& forward(U&& t) {
        return static_cast<U&&>(t);
    }
};
auto forward = [](auto&& t) { return forward_if_wrapper<decltype(t)>::forward(t); };
template <class T> auto forward_if = [](auto&& u) { return forward_if_wrapper<T>::forward(u); };

// --------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

template<class Elt>
void bar(Elt&& e) {
    printf("Called %s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

template<class Container>
void foo(Container&& c) {
    for (auto&& elt : c) {
        bar(forward_if<Container>(elt));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2};
    foo(v);
    foo(std::move(v));
}
```

The error I see from the second code with Clang is:

```
test.cc:34:13: error: called object type 'auto' is not a function or function pointer
        bar(forward_if<Container>(elt));
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:43:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'foo<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > &>' requested here
    foo(v);
    ^
```

I don't have access to any other compiler that supports C++14 generic lambdas, so Clang is all I've tested.

Is this my bug or Clang's bug?

I'm leaning toward the idea that it's a bug in Clang's template instantiation rules: Clang seems to be treating `auto` as a first-class citizen in the type world, instead of as an indicator to perform type deduction.

```
test.cc:34:14: error: invalid argument type 'auto' to unary expression
        bar((+forward_if<Container>)(elt));
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Again:

```
template<class T> T x{0};  // good
template<class T> auto x = T{0};  // bad

int main()
{
    return x<int> + x<long>;
}

bad.cc:6:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('auto' and 'auto')
```

Comment: The code snippet in your question compiles fine (after changing `class` to `struct` for accessibility) with a recent version of clang++. This suggests that the error you're seeing is a compiler bug that has been fixed.

Comment: @dyp Hooray! Can you tell me the output of `clang --version`? and ideally I'd like to find an online service like ideone or godbolt that supports that version of Clang. (http://ideone.com/jRZ5SD doesn't even support variable templates.)

Comment: [melpon.org/wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) typically has very recent versions of both g++ and clang++, but I'm not sure if you can adjust the compiler switches to something reasonable (like, `-std=c++1y`) -- edit: ah, you can adjust it at the bottom left of the page. [coliru.stacked-crooked.com](http://http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) also has reasonably recent versions of both g++ and clang++. I have used a clang version 3.7.0 (trunk 228504) which should be tip-of-trunk atm.

Comment: The clang++ on coliru is `clang version 3.5.0 (tags/RELEASE_350/final 217394)`, and said code (with the `struct` vs `class` fix) works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Per @dyp's and @ildjarn's comments: Yes, this was a bug in Clang 3.4 (and maybe 3.5). It is fixed in Clang 3.7.0 (and perhaps earlier). Various versions of Clang are available on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/).

And [here is the C++14 code I was trying to construct!](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ds6QEELr2THWrCJo)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct forward_wrapper {

    template <class U, class Enable = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(std::remove_reference<U>), std::is_reference<T>::value)>>
    static U forward(U&& u) {
        return u;
    }

    template <class U, class Enable = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(std::remove_reference<U>), !std::is_reference<T>::value)>>
    static decltype(auto) forward(U&& u) {
        return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type &&>(u);
    }
};

template <class T> auto forward =
    [](auto&& u) -> decltype(auto) { return forward_wrapper<T>::forward(u); };

// --------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

void bar(int &) { puts("Called copy function"); }
void bar(int &&) { puts("Called move function"); }

template<class Container>
void foo(Container&& c) {
    for (auto&& elt : c) {
        bar(forward<Container>(elt));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2};
    foo(v);
    foo(std::move(v));
}
```